# Pinia object loses reactivity after for each in Vue

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs, pinia

I have this nested foreach
**BalanceItemList.vue**

```
<template>
    <div v-for="category in categoryItemsStore.balanceCategories" :key="category.id" class="mt-5">
        <div class="border-black border-b bg-gray-200">
            <span class="font-bold w-full">{{ category.name }}</span>
        </div>

        <div v-for="balanceItem in category.balance_items" :key="balanceItem.id">
            {{ balanceItem.total = 500 }}
            <balance-item :balance-item="balanceItem" @update-balance-item="update"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <balance-item-create :category="category.id" @create-balance-item="update"/>
        </div>
        <div v-if="categoryItemsStore.totals[category.id]" class="grid grid-cols-4-b t-2 ml-2">
            <div :class="category.is_positive ? '': 'text-red-600' "
                 class="col-start-4 border-t-2 border-black font-bold">
                &euro;{{ categoryItemsStore.totals[category.id].total }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

I checked the reactivity from "balanceItem" like so

```
{{ balanceItem.total = 500 }}
```

And it get updated in the store but then i have my balance-item component:
**BalanceItem.vue**

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import NumberInput from "@/Components/NumberInput.vue";
import {UseCategoryItemsStore} from "@/Stores/UseCategoryItemsStore.js";

const categoryItemStore = UseCategoryItemsStore()

const props = defineProps({balanceItem: Object, errors: Object})

let item = reactive(props.balanceItem);

const form = useForm(item);

const emit = defineEmits(['update-balance-item'])

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route('balance-item.update'), {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () => {
            props.balanceItem.total = 500
            categoryItemStore.updateBalanceItemsTotals(form)
            emit('update-balance-item')
        }
    })

}

</script>

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-4-b">
            <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
            <NumberInput
                v-model="form.count"
                autofocus
                class=" mr-4 mt-1 block"
                type="number"
                @update:model-value="submit"
            />
            <div :class="item.item_category.is_positive ? '' : 'text-red-600'" class="flex place-items-center">
                <div class="pt-1 mr-1">&euro;</div>
                <NumberInput
                    v-model="form.amount"
                    :class="form.errors.amount ? 'border-red-600' : ''"
                    autofocus
                    class="mt-1 mr-4 w-5/6"
                    type="text"
                    @update:model-value="submit"
                />
            </div>
            <div :class="item.item_category.is_positive ? '' : 'text-red-600'" class="flex place-items-center">
                <div class="pt-1 mr-1 w-5/6">&euro;</div>
                <NumberInput
                    v-model="form.total"
                    autofocus
                    class="mt-1 block"
                    disabled
                    style="max-width: 95%"
                    type="text"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

This is my store where i test the reactivity. If i increase the number input the count from item remains the same
**UseCategoryItemsStore.js**

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import {ref} from "vue";

export const UseCategoryItemsStore = defineStore('UseCategoryItemsStore', () => {
    const balanceCategories = ref([])
    const totals = ref([])

    function getBalanceItems() {
        axios.get(route('balance-item.index')).then((response) => {
            balanceCategories.value = response.data
            // console.log(balanceCategories.value)
        })
    }

    function getTotals() {
        axios.get(route('balance-item.totals')).then((response) => totals.value = response.data)
    }

    function getData() {
        getTotals()
        getBalanceItems()
    }

    function updateBalanceItemsTotals(selectedItem) {
        balanceCategories.value.forEach((category) => {
            category.balance_items.forEach((item) => {
                if (item.id === selectedItem.id) {
                    // item.total = item.count * item.amount
                    console.log(item)
                }
            })
        })
    }

    getTotals()
    getBalanceItems()

    return {balanceCategories, totals, getBalanceItems, getTotals, getData, updateBalanceItemsTotals}
})
```

In this to test i do "props.balanceItem.total = 500". but if i check in the store it does not get updated. It look that assigning "balanceItem" to a prop it loses reactivity with my Pinia store. I can update my form manually with "form.total = form.count * form.amount" but that seem hacky to me i want to use the reactivity of the Pinia store. I thought about getting the Pina item based on that "BalanceItem" but that also seems hacky. Who knows why reactivity is lost?

I have laravel 10.39, vue3.2.41 and pinia 2.1.17 inertia 0.6.11. All the latest versions so far i know.

Comment: "loses reactivity with my Pinia store" - how exactly? "if i check in the store" - how? You shouldn't mutate props like `props.balanceItem.total = 500`. It's unclear what purpose `{{ balanceItem.total = 500 }}` serves, is it for testing?

Comment: Both are for testing reactivity

Comment: I added my store where i test the reactivity

Comment: The example is large enough and not easy to follow. Generally you need to clone store state to local form state (which wasn't done) and propagate the changes back to the store (which wasn't done either). There needs to be something like Object.assign(storeItem, formItem) on submit, something that I don't see here

Comment: The idea of pinia is that that is not necessary. balanceItem.total = 500 instantly updates the store without the need to propagate the changes (i checked it and it works). I'm quite new to all of this but that is how i learned it. it is after assigning it to a property in the for each when the reactivity is lost

Comment: I'm referring to {{ balanceItem.total = 500 }} in my for each

Comment: I could offcourse in BalanceItem.vue get the store and lookup the item but i'm not sure if that is the way

Comment: "The idea of pinia is that that is not necessary" - not really. Mutating store state directly in a form will result in poor design and being unable to sort out in which way data is mutated, which is the case here. And you will be unable to discard the changes if necessary, which may be not needed in this form but may be needed in another one. There are potential problems with your approach if you modify balance_items elements and "item" would refer to stale item. But in this case the problem is useForm, https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/blob/master/packages/vue3/src/useForm.ts#L50

Comment: It's implemented in a way it's incompatible with current approach. So cloning an item and submitting it back to the store is the way it's expected to be done here.

Answer (score 1):

I update my form and the store like so:

```
<script setup>
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import NumberInput from "@/Components/NumberInput.vue";
import {UseCategoryItemsStore} from "@/Stores/UseCategoryItemsStore.js";

const categoryItemStore = UseCategoryItemsStore()
const props = defineProps({balanceItem: Object, errors: Object})

let item = categoryItemStore.getItemById(props.balanceItem);

let form = useForm(item);

const emit = defineEmits(['update-balance-item'])

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route('balance-item.update'), {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () => {
            item = categoryItemStore.updateItem(form)
            form = useForm(item)
            emit('update-balance-item')
        }
    })

}

</script>
```

I added this functionality to my store:

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import {ref} from "vue";

export const UseCategoryItemsStore = defineStore('UseCategoryItemsStore', () => {
    const balanceCategories = ref([])
    const totals = ref([])

    function getBalanceItems() {
        axios.get(route('balance-item.index')).then((response) => {
            balanceCategories.value = response.data
            // console.log(balanceCategories.value)
        })
    }

    function getItemById(item) {
        let category = balanceCategories.value.find((category) => {
            return category.id === item.item_category_id
        })

        return category.balance_items.find((item_from_store) => {
            return item_from_store.id === item.id
        })
    }

    function updateItem(form) {
        const item = getItemById(form)
        item.count = form.count
        item.amount = form.amount
        item.total = item.count * item.amount

        return item
    }

    function getTotals() {
        axios.get(route('balance-item.totals')).then((response) => totals.value = response.data)
    }

    function getData() {
        getTotals()
        getBalanceItems()
    }

    getTotals()
    getBalanceItems()

    return {balanceCategories, totals, getBalanceItems, getTotals, getData, getItemById, updateItem}
})
```

The assumption that if the post get a 200 my formvalues can be used to update the store and to update the form. Its the best i could think of